# How to tell Flux.jl not to use the GPU?

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I am trying to setup my machine learning training loop and I don't want it to use the GPU on my computer. I have CUDA setup and installed but I want to run my code on the CPU instead. How do I do this in Flux.jl?

Comment: See here for discussion: https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/issues/1644 on this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Flux will not use the GPU unless you tell it to. First, ensure CUDA is not loaded my commenting out `using CUDA`. Next, remove any calls to `gpu`. In general, if you expect to be selectively running a program either on the CPU and GPU, then write your code using the following design pattern:

```
using CUDA
CUDA.allowscalar(false)
using Flux

# configure device
device = gpu

# made up function that loads your dataset
data = loaddata() .|> device

# made up function that builds your model
m = mymodel() |> device

# rest of your flux code
```

Notice how I used the generic `device` function everywhere so that I only need to set my chosen target device once atstart of the program. If your program is inside a “main” function, you could have that function accept a `device` argument.

If you absolutely need to disable the GPU, then CUDA.jl looks for the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable which you can set to be empty. But you would only need to do this for debug purposes/sanity checks.